# Configure Grunt File Name Matching for Files with Multiple Dots

Tags: gruntjs

I just started using grunt, and love it.
I keep running into an issue that seems like it might be pretty common.
Here it is. I have files named so that words after a dot are something like classes. eg:

```
layout.coffee
layout.blog.coffee
layout.site.coffee
```

My grunt task is configured to watch these files and translate them to js like this:

```
coffee:
  dev:
    files: [
      expand: true
      cwd: "<%= yeoman.app %>"
      src: ["**/*.coffee"]
      dest: "<%= yeoman.dev %>"
      ext: ".js"
    ]
```

The problem, I think, is that using `ext` makes the target for all three .coffee files the destination file `layout.js`, which isn't the intention.

Is there a nice way to configure grunt file mapping for filenames with multiple dots?

Right now I have to change my naming convention to use `-` instead of `.`, which is a drag :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the "Building the files object dynamically" section of [Configuring Tasks](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks).

Instead of specifying `ext`, you can specify `rename` which is a function that lets you create your own mapping for the file names.

The problem you are running into was brought up as an [issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/pull/750) on github and the answer from the grunt folks was that the "extension" of a file should be everything after the first "." instead of the last.

Hope that helps you!

Comment: Sure does. Looks like the Grunt team has taken a firm position on this one already.

Comment: FYI the **Configuring Tasks** documentation has moved [here](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks) now.

Answer (score 31):

Note that there is another option "extDot" that you can use to specify after which dot the ext should apply (first or last):

E.g.

```
files: [{
  expand: true,
  src: ['*.js','!*min.js'],
  dest: 'js',
  cwd: 'js',
  ext: '.min.js',
  extDot: 'last'
}]
```

Comment: That is perfectly valid, `extDot` was added in Grunt version 0.4.3. Just a note: unfortunately you may have a file named `filename.min.eco.js` (an Eco template precompiled to JST and then minified) in which case the extension is neither after the first dot, nor after the last (but still technically it is `js`). Another example would be `underscore.string.min.js.gz`. It's debatable and it's good to have options suiting everybody's needs to achieve what they want to.

Comment: To solve that they could change extDot to specify the nth dot - but I am guessing the use case is so small as to not have been required in the interim half a decade.

Answer (score 11):

That's the workaround I'm using in my projects:

```
uglify  : {
  build : {
    src     : ['**/*.js', '!*.min.js'],
    cwd     : 'js/',
    dest    : 'js/',
    expand  : true,
    rename  : function (dest, src) {
      var folder    = src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf('/'));
      var filename  = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('/'), src.length);

      filename  = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));

      return dest + folder + filename + '.min.js';
    }
  }
}
```

When the filename is like **jquery.2.0.3.js** then after minifying that it will be **jquery.2.0.3.min.js**.

Comment: You may or may not need to add `+ '/' +` after `return dest`

Comment: This works for grunt-contrib-less perfectly, but I had to remove the ext: property I had, that this example does not.