# grunt-sass dynamic file array configuration compiles to incomplete css files when multiple dots are in the filename

Tags: sass, gruntjs

Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15371443/510045

I am trying to configure grunt to dynamically compile my .scss files using grunt-sass. I'd like to compile only non-partial files but am running into an issue where if the filename has more than one dot in it, the compiled css filename is incomplete. Here is my configuration:

```
sass: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
            expand: true, // Enable dynamic expansion.
            cwd: 'sass/', // Src matches are relative to this path.
            src: ['**/*.scss', '!**/_*.scss'], // Actual pattern(s) to match. Compile all .scss files except partials
            dest: 'css', // Destination path prefix.
            ext: '.css', // Dest filepaths will have this extension.
        }]
    }
}
```

This works as expected except for those aforementioned multiple dot filenames. For example, a file named `some.jquery.plugin.scss` will get compiled to a file named `some.css` instead of `some.jquery.plugin.css`.

I've been digging around the [grunt documentation on files format](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-array-format) but am not having any luck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configure Grunt File Name Matching for Files with Multiple Dots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697344/configure-grunt-file-name-matching-for-files-with-multiple-dots)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More of a work around then answer for grunt-sass but if you use grunt-contrib-compass it allows for dots in the naming convention without any issues.

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass

You should already have ruby installed if you are using sass so shouldn't be a big effort to try and for the most part the configuration isn't that different.

Also might be worth trying https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass it's possible they've solved for this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the startup I was building this for ran out of funding so I won't be working on this anymore (at least not until the next time I use a Grunt workflow). I've accepted your answer as it offers some good alternatives.